# Shuffling with Java SecureRandom for crypto purposes?

Tags: java, random, cryptography, shuffle

I have a list of integers for which order is essential. The list can be very large, up to 2^24 elements. I would like to "encrypt" it in such a way that the original values, and their frequencies, remain the same; essentially, shuffling the list. I found that a very easy (but very insecure!) way to do it is using PRNGs, as Java.Random. The procedure would be seeding a PRNG with a key which sender and receiver share, and then applying any random sort algorithm (e.g. Fisher-Yates). This way, the receiver, knowing the key, would be able to "revert" the shuffling.

I know this is an *extremely bad* idea, but would it actually get better using SecureRandom? I understand its use is appropriate for crypto stuff, but I don't think it is meant to be used to output large lists of numbers.

(Overall, I know that "Never do your own algorithm" is crypto 101, but so far I haven't found any other algorithm which has the property I desire, of just "reordering" but keeping values and frequencies in the original list. If such a thing exists, could you please point me to it?)

Thank you! :)

Comment: What is the real problem that you're trying to solve. It can't be as simple as keeping the communication between sender and receiver secure, because you'd just encrypt the entire stream to do that. So what are you *really* trying to achieve.

Comment: Essentially, "obfuscating" parts of photos in a reversible way. Does it help?

Comment: Why don't you simply encrypt the part of the photo's you want to obfuscate? Oh, wait, you want them to remain "valid" photo's?

Comment: Exactly! Otherwise it would have a very big impact on the picture, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I recommend you close this question on StackOverflow and repost on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/. That will be a better forum for an open ended design question like this. StackOverflow is aimed for specific programming issues (normally accompanied by code), that have a specific, objective answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine, you just need to use a secure pseudo random stream. The easiest way to create this is a stream cipher, such as AES in CTR mode.

Implement a function `int Random(int count)` that reads 8 bytes from the stream, takes that integer modulo count, and uses that as building block in a Fisher-Yates shuffle. That's not perfectly uniform, but close enough to not matter in practice. If paranoid, up it to 16 bytes instead of 8.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of using stream encryption that way (I am just starting with crypto), and it seems to be promising! I'll look into it, accepting this as answer!